# Problem with running IOS simulator for my flutter app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, simulator

I'm trying to run my flutter app on the IOS simulator and its not working. So tried on the most basic flutter app (create my_app and then tried to run it) and nothing seem to work!
Everything seems to work fine when I run it from the terminal until the linking and signing phase and that where I get the error, how can I fix it?

This is the error I get:

```
Unable to install
/Users/MyUserName/Desktop/my_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on
82562E3A-E7BD-4FE0-9BF9-8BB9C7AD5F15. This is sometimes caused by a malformed
plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command
(domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Could not install at this time.
Failed to transfer ownership of path
/Users/MyUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/82562E3A-E7BD-4FE0-9BF9-8B
B9C7AD5F15/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoord
inationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/98CD703F-760F-4AAE-B991-BC2E
82D37D17/my_app.app to installd
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=103):
    Failed to transfer ownership of path
    /Users/MyUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/82562E3A-E7BD-4FE0-9BF9-8
    BB9C7AD5F15/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoo
    rdinationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/98CD703F-760F-4AAE-B991-B
    C2E82D37D17/my_app.app to installd
  Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 82562E3A-E7BD-4FE0-9BF9-8BB9C7AD5F15
  /Users/MyUserName/Desktop/my_app/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Edit:
I updated my MacOS, Deeleted and reinstalled Xcode, I even tried to run the most simple swift app and I get always this same error, it looks like the build was successful but it unable to install. I still get this same error, what can I do?

Comment: Are you running it from XCode or with flutter run? If you haven't tried, open the project workspace in XCode and try running from there. XCode sometimes gives better hints for errors

Comment: Close Other Xcode?

Comment: I updated my MacOS, Deeleted and reinstalled Xcode, I even tried to run the most simple swift app and I get always this same error, it looks like the build was successful but it unable to install. I still get this same error, what can I do?

Comment: In my case it happened because macOS was updating Xcode while I was using simulator. Solution is completely close "Simulator" app and restart it

Answer (score 33):

This occurred when I opened the Simulator first and then updated XCode -- even without running the app until after XCode updated completely.

What worked for me:

1. Close Simulator completely (from the dock, right-click -> "Quit")
2. Close XCode (if applicable)
3. Run `flutter clean`
4. Re-open Simulator
5. Re-open XCode and let it compile
6. Run the app again

If it still does not work, try resetting the device at "Device" -> "Erase All Content and Settings..." from the Simulator menu.

Comment: You may also need to do some work with your Podfile if you have any plugins installed. Referenced on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74739996/10044909

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue a couple of days ago

What I did - and what fixed the problem - was to reset the simulator (Device -> Erase All Content and Settings), and then run  `$ flutter clean`

You should now be able to run your app again

Answer (score 5):

To be honest. it's really frustrating for the developers

This is how I fixed!

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
pod repo update
pod install
cd ..
```

Then run the app, it works!

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me. I created another flutter application and copied it's ios folder to my project. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

This happens if the GoogleService-Info.plist is missing.

Comment: I am using flutterfire cli, does it also require to add GoogleServices-info.plist?

Answer (score 1):

Save time, just go to erase device content and settings from the emulator, then run flutter clean. App should run fine then.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `flutter clean` and then run your app again
2. If error persist, generate a new flutter project on Android studio. Replace the ${projectHome}/ios/Runner.xcodeproj folder with the ${newFlutterProjectHome}/iOS/Runner.xcodeproj. Your app should run fine now.
3. If error persist still, delete the ios folder and replace it with a new one copied from a freshly generated project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue recently. I found out I added my GoogleService-info.plist file to the subdirectory Runner and not the main Project directory Runner through xcode. I opened up xcode again, deleted the file and re-added it to the proper place and now everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when you have updated your XCode and your simulator is in the background.
Close the simulator and open the Xcode, you will get an option to install additional tools, install them and then run the application.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to run the Runner.xcworkspace app once from Xcode and this may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of hanging empty `GoogleService-Info.plist` file inside `Xcode` after migrating to new Firebase (FlutterFire) initialization.

`Xcode` is not a regular drag and drop IDE which directly maps project files to the ones in the file system. It rather caches file references. So even when you delete a `.plist` file, the `Xcode` still maintains a reference to it.

Simply opened `Xcode` IDE and removed `.plist` file (which updated `project.pbxproj` in turn). This helped me to compile the project fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
for this you have to give some value in CfBundleVersionShortString like
```

`<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>` 
`<string>1.0</string>`

And Give the build value in Runner as 1.0 and version as 1.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbTes.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete

- /android/app/build
- /build

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).